# how to stop a slideshow looping

Tags: javascript, loops, slideshow

I have a simple javascript slideshow which works well but currently loops but I only want it to run once then stop.  I've scratched my head over this for a while but unfortunately I'm not a coder so I come to you for help.  Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

// uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

// var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
// var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
// var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

 $(function() {
  setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 6000 );
 });

 </script>
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval = null;
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    var $next = $active.next();
    if($next.length == 0){
        // if there is no more images, don't loop but instead stop
        if(interval)
            clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({
            opacity: 0.0
        })
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000, function () {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function () {
    // make sure there is an .active image (preferably the first)
    if($('#slideshow IMG.active').length == 0)
         $('#slideshow IMG:first').addClass("active");

    // store the interval
    interval = setInterval("slideSwitch()", 6000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response.  That does sound logical but unfortunately I'm uncertain how to physically change the script correctly.  If you could show me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Just fixed a little mistake. `.addClass("active");` not `.addClass(".active");`.

Comment: Yes I noticed that.  Thanks.

Comment: **Step 1** you'll have to make sure there is an image with the class `active`, if not make the first one `active`. **Step 2**, when call `setInterval` we store a reference to that loop in the variable `interval` so when we reach the end we can stop the loop using that variable. That's all happen before we call `slideSwitch`. **Step 3**, inside `slideSwitch`, we look for the `active` element (100% exist because of step 1) and get the elements after it (`$next`). Now if there is no next elements (`$next.length == 0`) we stop the loop by calling `clearInterval` passing to it our ...

Comment: ... reference stored in `interval`, if there is next elements we just continue sliding. Hope this explanation is useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  It works great.  You're a star.